# How do I send signed emails from C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, email, cryptography, digital-signature

I need to send signed emails from within my C# .NET application.  Which is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: "not a real question" i really wonder who and why clicked it.

Comment: I see a question mark. Looks like a question to me.

Comment: Does it look better now, Andrey? I hope so!

Comment: check this also - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280391 (VB Code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This open source project contains everything you need to send signed emails.

[MailSystem.NET](https://github.com/pmengal/MailSystem.NET)

Answer (score 1):

hope this answers your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/845ff649-5c95-40a5-a813-1da8761102ab

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you need a component for S/MIME and PGP/MIME support, which includes samples and technical support, you can check [MIMEBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-mime.php) components of our SecureBlackbox. Both sending and parsing/processing of secure e-mails is supported.